# Stuck on ruby -v ruby 2.0.0p648 even though 2.3.1 is installed, how do i get it to change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried everything. Every YouTube guide. Nothing simply explains how to get from point A to point B.

Homebrew
Git
RVM
and Ruby are all installed.
For some reason Rails is not.

I'm new to the whole ruby thing, and getting everything installed has been an absolute nightmare. Everything is out of date. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have RVM installed correctly:

1) Open Terminal.

2) Type `rvm list` to see which versions of Ruby you have installed.

3) Type `rvm use ruby-2.3.1` if you want to use Ruby 2.3.1.

4) Type `rvm gemset create Rails500` to create a gemset for Rails 5.0.0

5) Type `rvm gemset use Rails500` to make Rails 5.0 your current gemset

6) Type `gem install rails -v 5.0.0` to install Rails 5 to your Rails500 gemset

7) Type `bundle install` bring everything up to date.

Now you have Rails 5.0 running under a Rails500 gemset against Ruby 2.3.1. Remember to `use ruby-2.3.1` and `use gemset Rails500` whenever you start a new session in Terminal if you want to maintain multiple versions of Ruby and multiple gemsets.

To make a version of Ruby default, type the following into Terminal:

```
rvm --default use 2.1.1
```

To keep a default gemset, just `rvm gemset use default` and make sure you install your gems into that `default` gemset by `use`-ing it before installation.

This covers 80% of everything you'll need to know about RVM.

Also, remember to never install rbenv, because it's not compatible with RVM -- stick with one or the other.

EDIT:

It seems you're having problems with your Terminal settings as well.

1) Open Terminal

2) From the Terminal menu, select Preferences

3) Select the Command (complete path) radio button

4) Make sure the text field beneath the radio button reads `/bin/bash`

5) Close the Preferences dialog and restart Terminal

6) Try using Ruby 2.3.1 via RVM

Comment: 1) Did it

2) 
# Zion at Franklins-MacBook-Pro.local in ~ [9:16:29]
→ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

3) → rvm use ruby-2.3.1

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
@MarsAtomic

Comment: See edited answer. You're not loading your bash profile.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in iTerm2 using Zsh? Because in my straight mac default terminal it is correctly now stating 2.3.1 as the Ruby v, but in iTerm2 zsh, it's still stating 2.0.0

Comment: At this point, your original question has been answered, so it would be a good gesture on your part to click the checkmark to the left of the answer to let people know that it helped you switch between versions of Ruby using RVM. Now you're asking a different question: "how do I set up iTerm Zsh." At this point, you have two choices: post a question in a forum more suited to tool discussion, like superuser or Google for info now that you know you're not loading your bash profile.

Comment: I'm new to Stack overflow & Development in general. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276703/how-to-make-zsh-run-as-a-login-shell-on-mac-os-x-in-iterm). You can get what you want by convincing iterm2 to run as a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed RVM,

```
rvm use 2.3.1
```

Then check gems in current  gemset using,

```
rvm gemset list ### gives a list of gemset for ruby 2.3.1
gem list ###installed gems in current gemset
```

Let me know,.if it didn't work.

Comment: It did not work, states "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work." And when I do rvm gemset list I got this "# Zion at Franklins-MacBook-Pro.local in ~ [9:12:26]
→ rvm gemset list

gemsets for system (found in /Users/Zion/.rvm/gems/system)
=> (default)
   *" @Hasmukh Rathod

Comment: I had the same issue.  First, solve the 'rvm use..' issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963018/rvm-is-not-a-function-selecting-rubies-with-rvm-use-will-not-work
Then follow the accepted answer and you should be on your way!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have got rvm, just write:

```
rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1
```

Then you can install rails by gem install rails command.

Comment: I do have RVM installed; 
→ rvm -v 
rvm 1.27.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

BUT when I do what you say, I get this : 
→ rvm use 2.3.1

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

Comment: It seems as if i'm missing some sort of correct preferences to allow me to use RVM as a function int he command line, im not sure. @batinex