# iTerm2 Setup as Login Shell, RVM Still Gives Error

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rvm, iterm2

I have been trying to install Ruby-2.6.1 on my Macbook Pro for a couple of days now, and I have followed many posts and blog posts to try to get the setup correct, but I am not successful. I always get the following when trying to set the default Ruby with RVM:

```
picklemac:~ jblanchard$ rvm use default ruby-2.6.1
```

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
>
> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
>   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.

I have followed the link, but with no success. I have iTerm2 setup as a login shell:

[image: iterm2 login shell selected]

In .bashrc I have the following:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And in .bash_profile I have the following:

```
# rvm
# export PATH="/Users/jblanchard/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

As I said, I have read and tried a number of things to get iTerm2 and my Mac setup properly, including [How to make zsh run as a login shell on Mac OS X (in iTerm)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1276703/1011527). Also, because I am trying to upgrade from Ruby 2.3 I have read a number of posts on just how to do that - again with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

### Additional Info

I am able to successfully list the installations using `rvm list`:

```
picklemac:~ jblanchard$ rvm list
   ruby-2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

This is interesting, because RVM indicates Ruby-2.6.1 is the default, but when I use `ruby -v` the return is:

> ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: What do you get when you `echo $SHELL` and `which rvm` from the command line? Is there any chance you're running zsh right now? If so, your bash profile scripts won't get evaluated and you'll need to add the lines from `.bash_profile` into your `.zshrc` file. Also, your iterm setup looks fine (that's how mine is configured)

Comment: I get `/bin/bash` @JayDorsey

Comment: `which rvm` yields `/Users/jblanchard/.rvm/bin/rvm` @JayDorsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully make the change to Ruby-2.6.1. First, I uncommented the `export` line in .bash_profile:

```
# rvm
export PATH="/Users/jblanchard/.rvm/bin:$PATH" #UNCOMMENTED
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

After stopping and starting iTerm2 I issued the command to use Ruby-2.6.1 and received a warning, but then:

```
picklemac:~ jblanchard$ rvm use default ruby-2.6.1
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.6.1
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
Using /Users/jblanchard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1
```

The change to Ruby-2.6.1 was made. It appears I do need to run `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` to fix the warning, which I would prefer to silencing it. Now, when running `ruby -v` the return is:

> ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin17]